# Need to remove app every time to make the changes

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to Arctic Fox. I have a strange problem with it, when I do changes in my application and run it again ( I'm not using fast run ), nothing changes in my app and I need to remove and reinstall the application.

This is very time-consuming and tiring.

How can I force it to make the changes without reinstalling the application?

I'm using a real phone and the problem has occurred since I installed the new Android Studio.

Comment: try to Build -> Rebuild project before every installation, you probably won't need to reinstall app every time, but still this is also time consuming, only little less... maybe help you until you find a fix

Comment: Try clearing %temp% folder  reinstalling Android studio. I didn't face any issue version 2020.3.1 patch 1.  Also make sure update is from stable version. Always update from stable channel.